# Getting the url of an image if selected

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm pretty new to js and having some trouble trying to get the img src next to a checkbox.

The structure of the elements looks like this:

`'<input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" id="myCheck" data-s3="object"><!--...--><img src="'+object2hrefvirt(s3exp_config.Bucket, data)+'" width="100" height="100">';`

Being **object2hrefvirt(s3exp_config.Bucket, data)** the image url.

The goal is to get all the urls to download them in a pack (not necessarily in a zip but to download all  the selected urls at once) when a button is clicked.

Here's what I have so far to know if a checkbox has been selected:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#download-checker').click(function(e) {
        checkDownload();
    });

    function checkDownload(){
        if(document.getElementsByTagName("input")){
            if(document.getElementById("myCheck").checked){
                //get img url
            } else if (!document.getElementById("myCheck").checked){
                alert("No selected files");
            } else {
                alert("Error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

*NOTE:* IDs need to be unique

```js
const checkDownload = () => {
  const list = $(".myCheck:checked")
    .map(function() { return $(this).next().attr("src") })
    .get(); 
  $("#list").text( list.join(", ")); // or return list.length>0 if you want    
}    
$(function() {
   $('#download-checker').on("click",checkDownload);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheck"  data-s3="object">
<img src="image1.jpg" width="100" height="100">
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" data-s3="object">
<img src="image1.jpg" width="100" height="100">

<button type="button" id="download-checker">Check</button>
<span id="list"></span>
```